# How to print Client IP Address/request ip, request body and user-agent in Strapi v4 logs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strapi, koa, headless-cms

I'm new to Strapi and Koa. I'm trying to generate strapi- console log output using custom log format.

For custom configuration of logging middleware in strapi, I came across following documentation: [logger middleware](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/required/middlewares.html#logger) which uses winstonjs for logging.

Custom Log format which I'm trying to generate should log in below format:

> [timestamp-YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS] - [loglevel] - [Client IP or REQUEST-IP] - [HTTP-METHOD REQUEST-URL - REQUEST_BODY(incase of POST) RESPONSE TIME(ms)- HTTP-STATUSCODE] [User-Agent]

As of now, I'm able to log following set of information- ***timestamp,loglevel,http-method,request-url,http-statuscode and http-response time***

The place where I'm stuck and scratching my head is in logging remaining set of parameters. **i.e. CLIENT_IP/REQUEST-IP, HTTP-Request Body and User-Agent**

Please suggest.